# Sending each line from text file to remote computer?

Tags: powershell

This is my script to whitelist IP in a remote system. I want my script to read data from a text file on my local system and then foreach line I want to execute the scriptblock on the remote server.

Text file looks like this:

```
url1
url2
url3
```

Here is my code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $($server.text) -Credential ciqdev\riteshthakur {
  param($a, $b, $c, $url)

  Set-Location "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"
$url | foreach {
  .\appcmd.exe set config "$_" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='$($a)',allowed='$($c)',subnetMask='$($b)']" /commit:apphost 
}
} -ArgumentList $ip.text, $mask.text, $allowed, (get-content "File location")
```

This adds provided ip to all the pages in all the websites in IIS. Please help.

Comment: What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: If i pass array to remote, it adds IP to allow entry for all the pages and folders of all the webites, while if i pass just one url it gets added for just passed url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Improved efficiency by generating the command dynamically, and invoking it once.

I'd suggest using a technique similar to the following, where you read in the text file as an array of lines, and then iterate over each line, generating the commands that you want to run on the remote system.

Once you've generated the command as a string, you simply call the static `[ScriptBlock]::Create()` method to create a `ScriptBlock` object, based on the command string, and pass that into `Invoke-Command`.

I'd suggest you get familiar with the concept of PowerShell Splatting, which I talk about in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkbSFXjTLOA. It's a really powerful concept, and helps make your code easier to read. The example code below uses PowerShell Splatting (available in PowerShell 3.0 and later).

```
### Read the text file on the local system
$Whitelist = Get-Content -Path IPwhitelist.txt;

### Generate the stub for the remote command
$RemoteCommand = @'
param($a, $b, $c)

Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
'@

### Add more commands to the remote command
foreach ($Line in $Whitelist) {
    $RemoteCommand += '{1}.\appcmd.exe set config "{0}" -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress=''$($a)'',allowed=''$($c)'',subnetMask=''$($b)'']" /commit:apphost' -f $Line, "`n";
}

### Invoke the entire remote command (once)
$Command = @{
    ComputerName = $Server.Text
    Credential = Get-Credential -Credential ciqdev\riteshthakur
    ScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create($RemoteCommand);
    ArgumentList = @($ip.text, $mask.text, $allowed)
    }
Invoke-Command @Command;
```

Comment: It means it will execute command on remote and for every new recursion it will come back to local for new data. Isnt it a lengthy method. Is there a way by which we can send array of data on remote and recursion takes place there only ? *thanks for help thugh*

Comment: @RiteshThakur I've changed the script to generate the command dynamically, and invoke it only one time. This will improve efficiency by reducing the number of remote WinRM connections.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet and iterate over each item using the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $($server.text) -Credential ciqdev\riteshthakur {
  param($a, $b, $c, $urls)

  Set-Location "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv"
  $urls | Foreach {
    .\appcmd.exe set config $_ -section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipAddress='$($a)',allowed='$($c)',subnetMask='$($b)']" /commit:apphost
  }
} -ArgumentList $ip.text, $mask.text, $allowed, (Get-Content 'Path_to_your_file')
```

Comment: what do i write in place of "data from each file" ?

Comment: martin can you explain ? does this mean that we are sending array of data once to remote and then rest is done there, or does it bounce back and forth between local and remote for data each time ?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question, I thought you want to inoke the block for each url... Try my edited answer.

Comment: This script adds entered IP for all the pages and folders of all the websites in IIS. WHile if i pass "site/abc/bcd.html" singly and manually, it gets added for just one page. Solution ?